# Check if certain character is supported by UIFont

Tags: ios, unicode, fonts, uifont

I know how to get the array of all fonts in iOS. Now I need to check if certain font support Cyrillic characters (Ukrainian alphabet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can check font for Cyrillic characters using this function:

```
CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters
```

If it returns False the font is improper.